# Problem for multiple foreign keys of the same model

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I am new to sequelize and I am using it to fetch a list of a nearby user. But I am getting the following error

AggregateReview is associated to User using an alias. You've included an alias (test), but it does not match the alias(es) defined in your association (AggregateReview)

My Model Below

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
const AggregateReview = sequelize.define(
    "AggregateReview",
    {
        review_type: {
            type: DataTypes.ENUM(
                reviewConstants.REVIEW_TYPE_PLATE,
                reviewConstants.REVIEW_TYPE_CHEF,
                reviewConstants.REVIEW_TYPE_DRIVER
            )
        },
        chefID: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            AllowNull: true,
            references: {
                model: "Users",
                key: "id"
            }
        },
        driverID: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            AllowNull: true,
            references: {
                model: "Users",
                key: "id"
            }
        },
        plateId: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            AllowNull: true,
            references: {
                model: "Plates",
                key: "id"
            }
        },
        userCount: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER
        },
        rating: DataTypes.DOUBLE
    },
    {}
);
AggregateReview.associate = function(models) {
    AggregateReview.belongsTo(models.User, {
        foreignKey: "driverID",
        as: "driver"
    });
    AggregateReview.belongsTo(models.User, {
        foreignKey: "chefID",
        as: "chef"
    });
    AggregateReview.belongsTo(models.Plates, {
        foreignKey: "plateId",
        as: "plate"
    });
};
return AggregateReview;
```

};

My Query Below

```
const roundDigit = 2;
const currentUserLocationLat = req.body.lat || req.user.location_lat;
const currentUserLocationLon = req.body.lon || req.user.location_lon;
const radiusDistance =
    req.body.radius || shippingAddressConstants.DEFAULT_RADIUS;
const radiusDistanceUnit =
    req.body.radiusUnit || shippingAddressConstants.DISTANCE_MILES;
const multiplier =
    shippingAddressConstants.radiusDistanceUnitHaversineMap[
        radiusDistanceUnit
    ];
const query = [
    [
        sequelize.literal(`(round(${multiplier} * acos( cos( radians(${currentUserLocationLat}) ) * cos( radians( location_lat ) )
  * cos( radians( location_lon ) - radians(${currentUserLocationLon}) ) + sin( radians(${currentUserLocationLat}) ) * sin(radians(location_lat))),${roundDigit}))
  `),
        "distance"
    ]
];
const where = { user_type: "chef" };
const having = { distance: { [Sequelize.Op.lte]: radiusDistance } };
const order = [[sequelize.col("distance"), "ASC"]];
const response = await User.findAll({
    where,
    attributes: ["device_id", "device_registration_token", ...query],
    include: [
        {
            model: AggregateReview,
            as: "chef"
        }
    ],
    having,
    order
});
return response;
```

My User Model

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
const User = sequelize.define("User", {
    name: DataTypes.STRING,
    email: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        unique: true
    },
    country_code: DataTypes.STRING,
    phone_no: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        unique: true
    },
    auth_token: DataTypes.STRING,
    restaurant_name: DataTypes.STRING,
    password: DataTypes.STRING,
    location_lat: DataTypes.DECIMAL(10, 8),
    location_lon: DataTypes.DECIMAL(10, 8),
    user_type: DataTypes.ENUM(
        userConstants.USER_TYPE_USER,
        userConstants.USER_TYPE_CHEF,
        userConstants.USER_TYPE_ADMIN,
        userConstants.USER_TYPE_DRIVER
    ),
    imagePath: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING
    },

    // for password reset
    password_reset_token: DataTypes.STRING,

    verification_email_token: DataTypes.STRING,
    verification_email_status: DataTypes.ENUM(
        userConstants.STATUS_PENDING,
        userConstants.STATUS_VERIFIED
    ),
    verification_phone_token: DataTypes.STRING,
    verification_phone_status: DataTypes.ENUM(
        userConstants.STATUS_PENDING,
        userConstants.STATUS_VERIFIED
    ),
    status: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    user_ip: DataTypes.STRING,
    stripe_id: DataTypes.STRING,
    provider: DataTypes.STRING,
    provider_user_id: DataTypes.STRING,
    promotionalContent: {
        type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
        defaultValue: false
    },
    device_id: DataTypes.STRING,
    device_registration_token: DataTypes.STRING,
    order_flag: {
        type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
        defaultValue: true
    }
});

User.associate = function(models) {
    User.hasMany(models.Plates);
    User.hasMany(models.OrderDelivery, { foreignKey: "driverId" });
    User.hasMany(models.Order);
    User.hasMany(models.ShippingAddress, { as: "address" });
    User.hasMany(models.CustomPlateAuctionBid);
    User.hasMany(models.Review);
    User.hasOne(models.AggregateReview, { foreignKey: "driverId" });
    User.hasOne(models.Documents);
    User.hasOne(models.Basket);
    User.hasOne(models.Wallet);
    User.hasOne(models.Transactions);
};
return User;};
```

Comment: I request you to share `User` model and its associations as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sequelize statement should be as follows -

```
const response = await User.findAll({
    where,
    attributes: ["device_id", "device_registration_token", ...query],
    include: [
        {
            model: AggregateReview,
        }
    ],
    having,
    order
});
```

You need to remove an alias of model `AggregateReview` as you have not defined any while defining association of `User` with `AggregateReview`. You have defined alias of `AggregateReview` as `chef` while defining an association of `AggregateReview` with `User`.